# How to assign Awk output to netcat?

Tags: awk, netcat

I want to transfer first field of a file. I am using awk to pull the first field and then send it using netcat. But I don't get anything on the otherside. I am using the following command

```
awk -F, '{print  $1}' sample.csv | netcat -lk 9999
```

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Laeeq

Comment: does `awk -F, '{print  $1}' sample.csv` display the first column of your csv file?

Comment: Yes it display's the first column.

Comment: How do you test on the client site?

Comment: Its an application which is not getting anything. Says empty string. But if there is a simple way to check, it would be helpful.

Comment: I'm using `telnet localhost 9999` to test the client. It works. (`nc localhost 9999` will work too)

Comment: You need to remove the `l` because that is for `listen`, i.e. the receiving end.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem when piping awk output to netcat. Turns out, awk buffers a lot.

Text can be flushed on each line with the fflush() command. The following works for me:

```
awk -F, '{print  $1} fflush()' sample.csv | netcat -lk 9999
```